# Ubuntu 16.04 problems with kernel 4.15.0

Tags: 16.04

I installed kernel 4.15.0. Then I installed nvidea 340.104 proprietary drivers. After rebooting I got a token error. Other kernels work with it. How do I fix that issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my opinion, the issue is related to the incompatibility between the 4.15 kernel and the Nvidia driver (340, in my case). Steps I took to solve the problem:

1. At the boot I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> and went to the grub options.
2. I chose the 4.13 kernel and the system booted up.
3. I installed `grub-customizer` and changed the kernel position at boot, to avoid do the same each time... But this process is not so complicated because we had already the previous 4.13 kernel installed, because this was not a 18.04 fresh install.

Optional:

You may enter the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install haveged
```

as described in this bug here; https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/linux/+bug/1779827

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of why but I know what because I ran into the same issue. It is not properly building and installing the modules for the booted kernel you use when installing nvidia drivers. If you boot to an older kernel, purge the problem kernel, reboot, then reinstall kernel, the proper modules should get built and installed then you can boot into latest.

If you have issues trying that you can remove nvidia and the problem kernel, boot to an unused kernel, install kernel first then nvidia and you should be fine.

This issue only happens with the kernel that is booted when you are installing the nvidia drivers. I figured out that was the issue, rather than try and track down why exactly it was that way, I just fixed.